# jQuery Mobile click event.preventDefault does not seem to prevent change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to prevent a radio button from changing when a use clicks, it works when using standard jQuery but when you include jQuery Mobile it does not seem to work, is there something else I have to do in jQuery Mobile?

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"  data-type="horizontal">
        <input type="radio" name="trade-direction" id="buy" value="B" checked="checked" />
        <label for="buy">Buy</label>

        <input type="radio" name="trade-direction" id="hold" value="H"  />
        <label for="hold">Hold</label>

        <input type="radio" name="trade-direction" id="sell" value="S"  />
        <label for="sell">Sell</label>
</fieldset>

$('[name="trade-direction"]:radio').click(function(event) {
    if(!confirm("Do You Want To Change?")) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

below is a link to the code in jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/mikeu/xJaaa/

Comment: How come it looks so nice ... I was expecting regular style radio box with no styles affected to them ... what am i not getting ?

Comment: The jQuery Mobile Checkbox is Checked.

Comment: @hayonj all the styling is done by jQuery.Mobile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that with jQuery.Mobile, the element that is effected by the UI change is not the input element.  In fact, the radio element isn't actually clicked at all.  The Element that is clicked is `<div class="ui-radio">`.  If you want to bind to the radio input itself, you need to use the `change` event, but in this case it won't work for you, because the function gets called after the change has already taken place.

What you need is something like this:

```
// Probably a good idea to give your fieldset an ID or class

 $('fieldset').delegate('.ui-radio','click',function(event){
      if(!confirm("Do You Want To Change?")) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
      } 
  })
```

The `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` prevents the the `.ui-radio` from triggering the click event to the input, and the `event.preventDefault` prevents the default action.  The `stopImmediatePropagation` may not be necessary, but it gives an added guarantee that may be helpful across different browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I dont seem to be able to get your code to work, any chance you could have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/mikeu/qe29J/ and let me know what i need to change?

Comment: Thanks, I have figured out the problem with the code, delegate was spelled incorrectly. I now have another issue the confirm dialog shows twice, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Whoops .. sorry about the spelling error.  I'll look at the other thing.

Comment: The confirm dialog only shows once on the fiddle I'm using, but I have a guess as to why it may be happening.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Im using Chrome Version 26.0.1410.65

Comment: It works in Safari on Mac, does not work in Chrome on mac or PC and IE 9

Comment: You took out `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.  When I put that back, it only shows once. *See the last paragraph of my answer.*  Also, the `return false` is not necessary, and probably should be excluded unless you are returning a different value when the user clicks `OK`.  Why?  Not sure exactly, but I think there are circumstances where unnecessary returns cause problems.