# Jquery event prevent default not working (jquery mobile and phonegap)

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form id="message">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <textarea id="messagefield" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I want to execute a function instead of the form submitting, so I have this at the bottom of my page:

```
$(function() {
    $("#message").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var recipient = $("#name").val();
        var message = $("#messagefield").val();
        send(recipient, message);
    });
});
```

But for some reason, 19/20 times when I press Send, the page reloads and the values in the inputs disappear. Any idea why this would happen? Sometimes when I go to the page, then refresh it, then fill out the form, it works.

I've found this thread: [Submit button does not work unless I refresh the page form_for Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339504/submit-button-does-not-work-unless-i-refresh-the-page-form-for-rails) for some reason I think cordova may be rendering the HTML incorrectly and then fixing it on reload like described here

Turns out that's what it was. Here is a screenshot of the rendered HTML:
[image: Imgur]

Some more useful information: [jQuery Mobile click event.preventDefault does not seem to prevent change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555138/jquery-mobile-click-event-preventdefault-does-not-seem-to-prevent-change)

Comment: Why don't you disable submit button during form submit `event` and enable it once submit is done and ajax is complete..??

Comment: Does the java function resides in a document.ready() function? and do you press Send before page finish load ??

Comment: `<form id="message">` and `<textarea id="message"` use same id, fix that

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I have for my actual code, I'll update what I wrote. In my code the textarea says messagefield

Comment: I tried wrapping it in document.ready, no luck.

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill where did you insert your script?? header or footer??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: 
it won't submit form

```
 <button type="button" name="theButton" id="msg">SUBMIT</button>

 $(function() {
$("#msg").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var recipient = $("#name").val();
    var message = $("#messagefield").val();
    send(recipient, message);
});
```

});

Comment: Same thing happens as before... for some reason when I press it, nothing happens. But whenever I refresh and press it, it works. Same goes for anchor tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please **return false;** at the end of your function.
may be form submit successfully and return true and so your controls are cleared.
As Below::

```
$(function() {
        $("#message").on("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var recipient = $("#name").val();
            var message = $("#messagefield").val();
            send(recipient, message);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: It's the weirdest thing. Because like I said above, when I navigate to the page, then refresh, it works fine.